# email body from a parsed email object in jython

Tags: python, email, jython, parsing

I have an object.

```
    fp = open(self.currentEmailPath, "rb")
    p = email.Parser.Parser()
    self._currentEmailParsedInstance= p.parse(fp)
    fp.close()
```

self.currentEmailParsedInstance, from this object I want to get the body of an email, text only no HTML....

How do I do it?

---

something like this?

```
        newmsg=self._currentEmailParsedInstance.get_payload()
        body=newmsg[0].get_content....?
```

then strip the html from body.
just what is that .... method to return the actual text... maybe I mis-understand you

```
        msg=self._currentEmailParsedInstance.get_payload()
        print type(msg)
```

output =  type 'list'

---

the email

Return-Path: 
Received: from xx.xx.net (example) by mxx3.xx.net (xxx)
        id 485EF65F08EDX5E12 for xxx@xx.com; Thu, 23 Oct 2008 06:07:51 +0200
Received: from xxxxx2 (ccc) by example.net (ccc) (authenticated as xxxx.xxx@example.com)
        id 48798D4001146189 for example.example@example-example.com; Thu, 23 Oct 2008 06:07:51 +0200
From: "example" 
To: 
Subject: FW: example
Date: Thu, 23 Oct 2008 12:07:45 +0800
Organization: example
Message-ID: <001601c934c4$xxxx30$a9ff460a@xxx>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0017_01C93507.F6F64E30"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 11
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2900.3138
Thread-Index: Ack0wLaumqgZo1oXSBuIpUCEg/wfOAABAFEA

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0017_01C93507.F6F64E30
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_001_0018_01C93507.F6F64E30"

------=_NextPart_001_0018_01C93507.F6F64E30
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

From: example.example[mailto:example@example.com]
Sent: Thursday, October 23, 2008 11:37 AM
To: xxxx@example.com
Subject: S/I for example(B/L
No.:4357-0120-810.044)

Please find attached the example.doc),

Thanks.

B.rgds,

xxx xxx

------=_NextPart_001_0018_01C93507.F6F64E30
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" =
xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" =
xmlns:st1=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" =
xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

HTML STUFF till

------=_NextPart_001_0018_01C93507.F6F64E30--

------=_NextPart_000_0017_01C93507.F6F64E30
Content-Type: application/msword;
    name="xxxx.doc"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="xxxx.doc"
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------=_NextPart_000_0017_01C93507.F6F64E30--

---

I just want to get :

From: xxxx.xxxx [mailto:xxxx@example.com]
Sent: Thursday, October 23, 2008 11:37 AM
To: xxxx@example.com
Subject: S/I for xxxxx (B/L
No.:4357-0120-810.044)

Pls find attached the xxxx.doc),

Thanks.

B.rgds,

xxx xxx

---

not sure if the mail is malformed!
seems if you get an html page you have to do this:

```
        parts=self._currentEmailParsedInstance.get_payload()
        print parts[0].get_content_type()
        ..._multipart/alternative_
        textParts=parts[0].get_payload()
        print textParts[0].get_content_type()
        ..._text/plain_
        body=textParts[0].get_payload()
        print body
        ...get the text without a problem!!
```

thank you so much Vinko.

So its kinda like dealing with xml, recursive in nature.

Comment: get_payload() will return the body of the message. If your messages are multipart you have to provide an index, as I said in the answer. Please be more explicit

Comment: so this is the output for  msg=self._currentEmailParsedInstance.get_payload(0);  
print msg;
"ImportError: no module named locale"

Comment: that is what i understand about when you say give it an index. I am sure i misunderstand you. Or I understand it like this newmsg=self._currentEmailParsedInstance.get_payload();
        body=newmsg[0].get_content....?;

Im trying to be as explicit as i can.

Comment: That ImportError is the key, jython is not exactly the same as python, sadly, try to import java.util.Locale;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you the contents of the message

```
self.currentEmailParsedInstance.get_payload()
```

As for the text only part you will have to strip HTML on your own, for example using BeautifulSoup.

Check [this link](http://www.python.org/doc/2.2.3/lib/module-email.Message.html) for more information about the Message class the Parser returns. If you mean getting the text part of messages containing both HTML and plain text version of themselves, you can specify an index to get_payload() to get the part you want.

I tried with a different MIME email because what you pasted seems malformed, hopefully it got malformed when you edited it.

```
>>> parser = email.parser.Parser()
>>> message = parser.parse(open('/home/vinko/jlm.txt','r'))
>>> message.is_multipart()
True
>>> parts = message.get_payload()
>>> len(parts)
2
>>> parts[0].get_content_type()
'text/plain'
>>> parts[1].get_content_type()
'message/rfc822'
>>> parts[0].get_payload()
'Message Text'
```

parts will contain all parts of the multipart message, you can check their content types as shown and get only the text/plain ones, for instance.

Good luck.

Comment: hi, just want the text, I want to throw away the html.
pls look at the question again

Comment: Please rewrite your question. How do those emails look like? What is the problem with what you get with get_payload()? Why do you use in one example self.currentEmailParsedInstance and in the other self._email?

Answer (score 0):

ended up with this

```
        parser = email.parser.Parser()
        self._email = parser.parse(open('/home/vinko/jlm.txt','r'))
        parts=self._email.get_payload()
        check=parts[0].get_content_type()
        if check == "text/plain":
            return parts[0].get_payload()
        elif check == "multipart/alternative":
            part=parts[0].get_payload()
            if part[0].get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                return part[0].get_payload()
            else:
                return "cannot obtain the body of the email"
        else:
            return "cannot obtain the body of the email"
```